# creating thousands of folders with different names

Tags: batch-file, cmd, directory

I have to create a couple of thousand directories. 
The directories look like this: 10P001 being YEAR/P,S,L,R,F/Numberfrom001to600

the letters are not systematic, so i have to write them for every folder.

my script until now looks like this, but cmd doesnt like the for loop.

```
     @echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set /p jahr=Welches Jahr?
set /p anzahl=Wieviele Projekte?
set looop=%anzahl+1000

for /l %%x in (1001, 1, looop) do (
    set nummer=%%x
    set /p welches=P1 S2 L3 R4 F5 nichtexistent6?
    if %welches%==1 mkdir %jahr%P!nummer:~-3!
    if %welches%==2 mkdir %jahr%S!nummer:~-3!
    if %welches%==3 mkdir %jahr%L!nummer:~-3!
    if %welches%==4 mkdir %jahr%R!nummer:~-3!
    if %welches%==5 mkdir %jahr%F!nummer:~-3!
    if %welches%==6 echo "nicht existent"
)
pause
```

Comment: You are not using `anzahl` in your program. Where does it fit in? You can't `set` a variable within a block (a parenthesised sequence of commands) **and** use %var% to access the *changed* value; you must use `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` and then access the `changed` value using `!var~` (or `!welches!` in your case)

Comment: anzahl is not used yet, i deleted it from the code example, sorry for that.
the problem is not with %welches%, that one works. the prblem is that the for loop is not working and the %%x%%

Comment: It's very difficult to see what you are trying to do. You need to use `!welches!` in your `if` statements, not `%welches%` because you are changing `welches` within the `for /L %%x...` block. Are you aware that the way you have set this up you will be entering a response for each of the (600?) entries you want to create?

Comment: i have to enter a response for every entry because the letters SPDFLR are not systematic and i have to read it from a folder where the projects are handwritten. i have to create folders like this: 14P001 14S002 14P003 14L004 14R005 14R006 14R007 14P008 etc

i am not familiar with the windows command.
until now i entered the projects liket his: mkdir 14P003 14L004 14R005 14R006 14R007 14P008 etc which takes a long time

Comment: This is being read from handwritten pieces of paper or from a file? If from a file, please post a sample of the file.

Comment: sorry, it is read from a handwritten piece of paper

Comment: You say that it it is a handwritten file (again). What do you mean? Is it on paper or is it a computer file that someone has typed in?

Comment: piece of paper sorry

Comment: Could you type the data into a file, say in the format `001 P` `002 S` (one entry to a line). It would be a ten-second task to create a file containing all of the required lines, you then could edit it and then process it to produce your required directories?

Comment: ok you gave me a very good idea :) i will try to implement it and post my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
FOR /f "tokens=1,2delims= " %%a IN (q28608207.txt) DO ( 
 FOR /l %%x IN (1001,1,1011) DO (
  SET seq=%%x
  ECHO(MD %%a%%b!seq:~-3!
 )
)

GOTO :EOF
```

I used a file named `q28608207.txt` containing this data for my testing.

```
10 P
10 S
```

The routine reads the two fields from the file as `%%a` and `%%b`, then for a loop varying `%%x` from 1001 by 1 to 1011 (it can of course be 1600 - 1011 just proves the point), copy `%%x` to a temporary veriable (because substringing can't be applied to the metavariable `%%x`) create a directory named %%a%%b and the last 3 characters of the temporary variable.

Note that the `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` command enables the use of `!var!` (accessing the value of `var` as it varies)

The required MD commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, change `ECHO(MD` to `MD` to actually create the directories. Append `2>nul` to suppress error messages (eg. when the directory already exists)

---

To create a file containing the required numbers:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set /p jahr=Welches Jahr?
set /p anzahl=Wieviele Projekte?
set looop=%anzahl+1000

(
for /l %%x in (1001, 1, looop) do (
    set nummer=%%x
    echo %jahr%P!nummer:~-3!
)
)>J%jahr%.txt
```

This would produce a list (for jahr=14,say) in `J14.txt`

```
14P001
14P002
14P003
```

and then all you need do is edit the file (use notepad, not a word-processor) to replace the "P" with whatever letter is required. delete any line where no directory is required.

The resultant file could then be processed to directories by using

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
FOR /f %%a IN (J14.txt) DO ( 
  ECHO(MD "%%a"
)
GOTO :EOF
```

Comment: thank you very much for your answer. the only thing that now doesnt work, is the FOR loop. the program crashed when it tries to go into the for loop.

for /l %%x in (1001, 1, 1500) do (
          //do stuff here
)

that doesnt work somehow

Comment: Can't tell what the problem is without seeing exactly what code you are using. Please `edit` you question to include an exact copy (by cut-and-paste) of your code. As posted, it worked perfectly happily for me. Please also say what the crash report was.

Comment: i have edited the main question to show the code as it is right now. there is no error message, the program just jumps over the loop

Comment: @Stephan yeah thats true, but then there's an error saying that mkdir cant be worked with syntactic... well i did something you all will hate me for, its in the answer from me :)

Answer (score 0):

my solution for now (i know its worse than bad habit, but it works and will save me a lot of time (or at least my company some money)):

```
 @echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set /p jahr=Welches Jahr?
set /p anzahl=Wieviele Projekte?
set /a looop=%anzahl%+1000
set /a count=1001
:LoopStart
    set /p welches=P1 S2 L3 R4 F5 nichtexistent6?
    if !welches!==1 mkdir %jahr%P!count:~-3!
    if !welches!==2 mkdir %jahr%S!count:~-3!
    if !welches!==3 mkdir %jahr%L!count:~-3!
    if !welches!==4 mkdir %jahr%R!count:~-3!
    if !welches!==5 mkdir %jahr%F!count:~-3!
    if !welches!==6 echo "nicht existent"

set /a count=%count%+1
if %count% leq %looop% (goto LoopStart) else (goto:eof)
pause
```